# Атомарные операции

Tags: многопоточность, rust, mutex, atomic

Есть следующий код:

```
extern crate rayon;

use std::sync::atomic::{
    Ordering,
    AtomicUsize,
};



fn main() {
    let count = AtomicUsize::new(0);

    rayon::join(
        || loop { count.store(1, Ordering::Relaxed) },
        || loop { println!("count = {}", count.load(Ordering::Relaxed)) }
    );
}
```

Я ожидал, что первый поток будет в цикле увеличивать атомарную переменную на 1, а второй в цикле будет ее выводить, но получается так, что первый поток увеличивает переменную всего один раз, а второй поток выводит ее не прерываясь. Почему такое происходит и как можно решить эту проблему? С mutex-ами все работает, но я бы не хотел блокировать поток ради простого инкремента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что проблема в использовании функции [`store`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.store) - она же просто записывает литерал `1` каждый раз. Если переписать с использованием [`fetch_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicUsize.html#method.fetch_add):

```
extern crate rayon;

use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};

fn main() {
    let count = AtomicUsize::new(0);
    rayon::join(
        || loop { let _ = count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed); },
        || loop { println!("count = {}", count.load(Ordering::Relaxed)) },
    );
}
```

... то наблюдаемое поведение становится похоже на желаемое:

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.06s
     Running `target/debug/rayon_test`
count = 3882
count = 20199
count = 20375
count = 20436
count = 20480
count = 20529
count = 20572
count = 20616
```

Comment: действительно глупо с моей стороны